# ASP.NET MVC App connection with SQL-Server on which protocol?

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc, sql-server

I have a ASP.NET MVC application and connects to the SQL Server running on a different server. I wish to know which is the **default protocol** used between the MVC app and SQL-server to exchange the data.

Comment: You can check out the MSDN pages about [Network Protocols](https://technet.microsoft.com/hu-hu/library/ms187892(v=sql.105).aspx) and their [defaults](https://msdn.microsoft.com/hu-hu/library/mt761720). However your question is too broad and lacks minimal research effort and might get closed/deleted if you keep it this way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"By default, the default protocol for SQL Server clients is TCP/IP. If the connection cannot be made using TCP/IP, the other enabled protocols are attempted. A shared memory connection cannot be made over a network. Use SQL Server Configuration Manager to enable or disable client protocols, and to change the order in which connection attempts are made"

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190204(v=sql.105).aspx

Basically you specify it in your connection string and it can fall back through negotiation with the server

Comment: Yeh, this link is useful and i was looking for such kind of information. Thanks.